# Search by JSONB field value. How to prepare query correctly using jooq?

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, jooq, jsonb

I'm trying to find records by condition from the jsonb field (array). I'm using the jsonb_exists_all function for this.
I wrote a working SQL, but I ran into the problem of creating correct Java code (Jooq) with argument binding.

For example, the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id int,
    data jsonb
);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
(1, '{"roles": ["ONE", "TWO", "FIVE"]}'),
(2, '{"roles": ["ONE", "SIX"]}');
```

And in my raw working SQL query, I'm searching by array values. This work.

```
SELECT
    id,
    data
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    jsonb_exists_all(mytable.data -> 'roles', array['ONE','TWO'])
```

In the next step, I'm trying to write Java code, and I'm having some issues with bindings (arguments) to implement a secured request.

```
String args = "'ONE','TWO'";

Flux.from(dsl.selectFrom(MyTable.MYTABLE)
          .where(noCondition().and("jsonb_exists_all(parameters -> 'roles', array[" + args + "])")))
          .map(record -> record.into(MyTableDto.class))
          .collectList();
```

Is it possible to do binding without concatenation?

I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, [with jOOQ, you should *never* concatenate strings](https://blog.jooq.org/never-concatenate-strings-with-jooq/). There's almost always a better way.

In your case, you could use [plain SQL templates](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) as follows:

```java
.where("json_exists_all({0}, {1})",
    jsonGetAttribute(MYTABLE.DATA, inline("roles")),
    val(new String[] { "ONE", "TWO" })
)
```

This is using:

- [JSON attribute access](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/json-attribute-access/)
- [`DSL::val`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val(T)) to create [bind values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/)
- [`DSL::inline`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline(T)) to create [inline values](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters/)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Lukas Elder, I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using the 3.16 version of Jooq. Is there a path to do the same on 3.16?

Comment: вот мое решение под версию <3.18 

.where("jsonb_exists_all(data -> {0}, {1})",
                                inline("roles"),
                                val(new String[] {"DONE", "NONE" })))

Comment: @Dmtry: Why not upgrade? Anyway, just look at plain SQL templates and study what it does. The answer is there.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Eder! Unfortunately, we are using Java 11 and the open-source version of Jooq and can't upgrade Java versions. The open-source version of Jooq, that supports Java 11 is 3.16 right now, and a higher version requires Java 17. We will try to upgrade our JVM.)